# Is it possible to intercept delegate method call in UICollectionView subclass?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegate

I am implementing a single row carousel view by subclassing UICollectionView and UICollectionFlowLayout. The visual looks similar to the following:
[image]

I want to only enable touch on the middle cell and disable the rest. Currently, I put the enabling/disabling logics in the delegate class as follow:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kButtonCollectionViewCellIdentifier
                                                                       forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // ...

    cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    return cell;
}


- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
{
    CGPoint midPoint= CGPointMake(self.collectionView.center.x + self.collectionView.contentOffset.x,
                                  self.collectionView.center.y + self.collectionView.contentOffset.y);
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:midPoint];

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

I would like to move this logics into my UICollectionView subclass, as it feels neater. So, is there a way for me to intercept the delegate calls in my UICollectionView subclass and add the above logics?

Comment: Did you try `self.delegate = myViewController;` ?

Comment: It would be easier to intercept shouldSelect/didSelect cell and work out if that cell is in the centre IMO.

Comment: @RomanSimenok the current disabling/enabling logics is already implemented in the a viewcontroller which is a delegate of my UICollectionView subclass

Comment: @SeanLintern88 There are some touchable UI elements in each cell, such as UIButton. This is the reason why I want to disable non-centre cells. I am not sure shouldSelect/didSelect will work.

Comment: Is the code above in your view controller? Does your view controller implement other collection view or scroll view delegate methods? Is it just the enable/disable logic that you want to move to your UICollectionView subclass?

Comment: I just want to hide the disabling/enabling logics in the UICollectionView subclass.